# Send RControl keystroke from VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros, ascii, sendkeys

I'm working on a VBA macro which needs to send a series of keystrokes.  For this application, I need to send a keystroke for Right Control.  Just the normal control is not sufficient.  I've seen the SendKeys method, but I don't see where you can specify *which* Control key is sent.  I'm hoping it's a quick and simple answer.  Thanks!

P.S. I'm still learning SO, so please let me know if I need to add or change something to comply with community standards.  I'll be glad to modify the post.  Thanks!

Comment: You will likely require the Win APi's SendMessage. You will need to know if you need 32-bit, 64-bit or both and what hte control code for the right [ctrl] key is. See [SendMessage function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using : {RCTRL}

https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I just tried it and it seems that this doesn't work in VBA.  It crashes the sub procedure.  If you know of a way of bundling an autoitscript into the office file and calling it with VBA that might also work.